# Checking password in Android

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-activity, passwords

I want to check the password and i have a password field for that in Android

```
    package com.example.berk4;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button buttonEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String password = et.getText().toString();

    et.getEditableText().toString();
    if (password.equals("admin")) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.berk4.screen2");
    startActivity(intent2);

    }else{

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("you suck");
        builder.setMessage("try again");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    }

}

}
```

When i write a random wrong password it works fine but when i write the correct password, the application shuts down,  Why it doesnt work for me ? (btw. i have another class screen2.)

Comment: have you added screen2 activity to manifest file ?

Comment: Did you add your screen2 activity in manifest xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start New Activity as if password is correct :

```
 if (password.equals("admin")) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,screen2.class);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }else{
    // your code here
  }
```

and also make sure you have added your Next Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
.....
<activity android:name=".screen2"></activity>
</application>
.....
```